# Hello Techies , I want to get below output based on SharePoint list , I have emp list and the task list

Tags: list, sitepages

I want to get below output based on SharePoint list. Everyday employees update daily task based on task list.

Task list 1 - 30 min, task 2 - 20 min and so on.

I want below output based on that input details. Can anyone help me on this?

[image]